# Displaying data from API in accordion

Tags: javascript, dom

I have some data from an API which I'm displaying on my web page. I've also got some simple HTML for an accordion. I have 4 lots of data and I want to display only one lot per slide on the accordion.
How would I do this? I would like to know how to separate the data for each slide based on my code.

```
$( function() {
  $( "#top-stories" ).accordion();
});

fetch('https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/technology.json?api-key='')
.then((resp) => resp.json())
.then(function(data) {
   const accordionSlides = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-slide");
   data.results.slice(0, 4).forEach((accordion, i) => {
    accordionSlides[i].innerHTML = `
      <h1>${accordion.title}</h1>
      <p>${accordion.url}</p>
      <p>${accordion.abstract}</p>
      <p>${accordion.published_date}</p>
      <img src="${accordion.multimedia[4].url}"/>`;
  })

})
```

```
<html>
 <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="top-stories">Top Stories</h1>
            <h3 class="accordion">Story 1</h3>
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="accordion-title"></div>
            </div>

            <h3 class="accordion">Story 2 - Collapsed</h3>
            <div class="panel">
                    <div class="accordion-title"></div>
            </div>

            <h3 class="accordion">Story 3 - Collapsed</h3>
            <div class="panel">
                    <div class="accordion-title"></div>
            </div>
            <h3 class="accordion">Story 4 - Collapsed</h3>
            <div class="panel">
                    <div class="accordion-title"></div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're open to using jquery-ui library, the following should work.

---

First of all, your HTML should be something as below:

```
<html>
 <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="top-stories">Top Stories</h1>
            <h3 class="accordion">Story 1</h3>
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="accordion-slide"></div>
            </div>

            <h3 class="accordion">Story 2 - Collapsed</h3>
            <div class="panel">
                    <div class="accordion-slide"></div>
            </div>

            <h3 class="accordion">Story 3 - Collapsed</h3>
            <div class="panel">
                    <div class="accordion-slide"></div>
            </div>
            <h3 class="accordion">Story 4 - Collapsed</h3>
            <div class="panel">
                    <div class="accordion-slide"></div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've changed the ID's to classes and replaced buttons with h3 tags. Also, I've added a link to the jquery-ui library.

And then the JS would mostly be as suggested by @marzelin with the addition jquery-ui accordin library initialization:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#top-stories" ).accordion();
});

fetch('https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/technology.json?api-key="."')
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then(function(data) {
     const accordionSlides = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-slide");
     data.results.slice(0, 4).forEach((accordion, i) => {
      accordionSlides[i].innerHTML = `
        <h1>${accordion.title}</h1>
        <p>${accordion.url}</p>
        <p>${accordion.abstract}</p>
        <p>${accordion.published_date}</p>
        <img src="${accordion.multimedia[4].url}"/>`;
    })

  })
```

Comment: I've mostly used the JS from @marzelin's answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer but now the data won't appear at all.

Comment: Is there an error in the JS? Have you checked the console?

Comment: I am recieving this error - Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined
    at index.js:25
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at index.js:24. I will update my question with the code.

Comment: Make sure that you have this line above the foreach `const accordionSlides = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-slide");` and that the div's have the class `accordion-slide` as in the html code i have put in the answer. If the error still persists, you might need to show the code.

Comment: The problem was in my code! Sorry for that. I've edited the class names in html from `accordin-title` to `accordin-slide`. Just do that and you will be good to go!

Comment: Also, remove your API Key from your Question

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've just changed the names to accordion-slide and it has worked!

Answer (score 0):

change `<div id="accordion"></div>` to `<div class="accordion-slide"></div>` and then:

```js
fetch('https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/technology.json?api-key="."')
  .then((resp) => resp.json())
  .then(function(data) {
     // get all slides
     const accordionSlides = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-slide");
     data.results.slice(0, 4).forEach((accordion, i) => {
      // insert content into a given slide
      accordionSlides[i].innerHTML = `
        <h1>${accordion.title}</h1>
        <p>${accordion.url}</p>
        <p>${accordion.abstract}</p>
        <p>${accordion.published_date}</p>
        <img src="${accordion.multimedia[4].url}"/>`;
    })

  })
```